# Docker and single python file

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a python program that uses `raw_input` to capture input from a give user, I also utilize a while loop to make sure I actually am getting the desired input.

Here is what it looks like

```
while True:
     marathon_host = input("Enter the DNS hostname or IP of your Marathon Instance:")

     if not marathon_host:
         print("Please enter a value!")
         continue
     else:
         break
```

I have several input variables that are setup like this. I'm now trying to dockerize the whole .py. I'd like create a docker image for this program and I don't know how to figure out input variables through docker/python.

Any help on how to start or where to read more on how to do this would be really appreciated. I'd like to be able to specify docker environments that reflect to these input variables as if a user is actually going through the prompt.

Comment: Do you have a Dockerfile? What have you tried on that end?

Comment: This is what my docker file looks like right now - I'm VERY new to docker.

`FROM python:3.5
COPY . /
CMD ['marathon-autoscale.py']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty open ended, as there are several solutions available. One way to do it would be to redirect stdin:

```
sys.stdin = open('path_to_input_file')
raw_input('Prompt: ')
```

You could also pass in a serialized answerfile (json or yaml are easily supported) and just set the input values accordingly without prompting if the file is provided, which is the route I would recommend.

Comment: Thanks, I used your advice and it definitely worked. I had a separate file called config maintaining all the environment variables and I check in my program if it exists or not and act accordingly. :)